# Ubuntu Freezes with USB reconnect for unknown reason

Tags: 14.04, usb, kernel, freeze

I have a Ubuntu Server 14.04.2 running Kodi Media Center on X. I have a 25' USB extension to a powered hub with an IR receiver and USB to Serial adapter. This was working great until I upgraded and found the newer kernel would not work with my j1900 processor. So I went back to 14.04.2 fresh and now I get a hard lock when the USB devices reset.

Comment: `This page has been removed!` – Please update your kernel log and include the output of `lsusb -v` in your question.

Comment: Thanks for noticing @DavidFoerster. I no longer have this problem (Or the setup actually) I answered the question already. I will remove the link and leave the symptoms incase they are useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the USB to Serial (RS232) adapter was the cause of the issue. Mixed with the long cable run it was going into a never ending restart which caused a kernal panic. I am not quite sure why but a better Adapter solved all the issues.